# Compress secp256k1 elliptic curve x, y coordinates strings strings into hex public key

Tags: python, ecdsa, elliptic-curve, python-cryptography

## For context

I am using the `azurerm_key_vault_key` terraform resource to create an secp256k1 key. I can output the X and Y coordinates for this key as strings that look like this (appears to be a base64 url-encoded, but I cannot find any docs that clearly define this)

```
"x": "ARriqkpHlC1Ia1Tk86EM_bqH_9a88Oh2zMYF3fUUGJw"
"y": "wTYd3CEiwTk1n-lFPdpZ51P4Z0EzlVNXLvJMY-k55pQ"
```

## The problem

I need to convert this into a public key in hexadecimal format. I have tried the following in Python:

```
import ecdsa
import binascii
import base64

def base64url_to_bytes(base64url_string):
    padding = '=' * (4 - (len(base64url_string) % 4))
    base64_string = base64url_string.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/') + padding
    return base64.b64decode(base64_string)

def compress_point(x, y):
    """Compresses the point (x, y) to a 33-byte compressed public key."""
    prefix = "02" if y % 2 == 0 else "03"
    return prefix + x

def decompress_point(compressed_key):
    """Decompresses the compressed public key to (x, y)."""
    prefix = compressed_key[:2]
    x = compressed_key[2:]
    y = ecdsa.ellipticcurve.Point(ecdsa.SECP256k1.curve, int(x, 16), int(prefix, 16))
    return x, y.y()

x_value = base64url_to_bytes("ARriqkpHlC1Ia1Tk86EM_bqH_9a88Oh2zMYF3fUUGJw")
y_value = base64url_to_bytes("wTYd3CEiwTk1n-lFPdpZ51P4Z0EzlVNXLvJMY-k55pQ")


x, y = int.from_bytes(x_value, byteorder='big'), int.from_bytes(y_value, byteorder='big')

# Compress the point
compressed_key = compress_point(format(x, 'x'), y)
print(compressed_key)

decompressed_x, decompressed_y = decompress_point(compressed_key)
print("Decompressed X:", decompressed_x)
print("Decompressed Y:", decompressed_y)
```

It compresses, but `decompress_point` throws an assertion error, which suggests that I am doing something wrong either in the compression or decompression step.

Here is the full output of the script above:

```
0211ae2aa4a47942d486b54e4f3a10cfdba87ffd6bcf0e876ccc605ddf514189c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_public_key3.py", line 32, in <module>
    decompressed_x, decompressed_y = decompress_point(compressed_key)
  File "get_public_key3.py", line 19, in decompress_point
    y = ecdsa.ellipticcurve.Point(ecdsa.SECP256k1.curve, int(x, 16), int(prefix, 16))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ecdsa/ellipticcurve.py", line 1090, in __init__
    assert self.__curve.contains_point(x, y)
AssertionError
```

I am not at all familiar with the packages in use here and the code above has mostly been put together from various bits and pieces I could find online.

Could someone provide me with a definitive answer on how to do this?

Comment: Which inputs are you looking for? All the functions and inputs that are relevant have been included. Have you tried running it yourself? Is there anything that does not work aside from the assertion error? And since you asked, the error not very verbose: it is literally just "AssertionError". I am not looking to resolve that error per se, but the error is an indication that the compression did not work correctly (or perhaps my decompression code is wrong, that is of course possible).

Comment: I did a quick search for the "ecdsa.ellipticcurve.Point" and I found the source code [here](https://github.com/tlsfuzzer/python-ecdsa/blob/3a85d22/src/ecdsa/ellipticcurve.py#L1090C4-L1090C4).  You're supposed to pass an X and Y coordinate to that function, but you don't have an X and Y coordinate: the whole point of the compression is that you just store the X coordinate, and you also store a single bit necessary to determine what the Y coordinate is.  Searching for the word "compressed" in that library's [README](https://github.com/tlsfuzzer/python-ecdsa) might help you.

Comment: Honestly, I am starting to think you did not even read the question. I never said an elliptic curve has URLs. I have two coordinates, X and Y, encoded in what is (probably) base64 url encoding. Yes, I know that is the point of compression. That is what I am trying to do. I am uncertain whether the compression is being done correctly, since decompression yields an error.

Comment: My comment made specific references to the function that gave the assertion error and then it explained the problem with how you called it, and pointed you to the solution.  This could only be done by carefully reading the code you posted.
 The key thing was to call `VerifyingKey.from_string` to reconstruct the Y coordinate, which was explained in the README I pointed you to and in the answer you accepted.

Comment: No one that reads this wil ever again know what your comments said since you decided to delete them after I responded to them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64url is a common encoding, your x and y look formally Base64url encoded. Also, a Base64url decoding provides an EC point valid for secp256k1:

```py
...
x_value = base64url_to_bytes("ARriqkpHlC1Ia1Tk86EM_bqH_9a88Oh2zMYF3fUUGJw")
y_value = base64url_to_bytes("wTYd3CEiwTk1n-lFPdpZ51P4Z0EzlVNXLvJMY-k55pQ")

x, y = int.from_bytes(x_value, byteorder='big'), int.from_bytes(y_value, byteorder='big')

point = ecdsa.ellipticcurve.Point(ecdsa.SECP256k1.curve, x, y)
print(point) # (499815257955367864408742079034045137860289053987516893620084695066060527772,87391995603390372321291482400901178939983763504428780242289494985570894079636)
```

An invalid EC point would result in an error message. So it is most likely indeed a Base64url encoding.

---

Converting your Base64url encoded x and y coordinates to a compressed or uncompressed key is easy. You don't even need the *ecdsa* library.

Note that for secp256k1 x and y must each have a size of 32 bytes in compressed or uncompressed format. If they should have numerically a value, which is smaller, they are to be padded from the front with 0x00 values to 32 bytes. A possible conversion looks as follows:

```py
...
x_value = base64url_to_bytes("ARriqkpHlC1Ia1Tk86EM_bqH_9a88Oh2zMYF3fUUGJw")
y_value = base64url_to_bytes("wTYd3CEiwTk1n-lFPdpZ51P4Z0EzlVNXLvJMY-k55pQ")

# padding with leadng 0x00 values
x_32 = (32 - len(x_value)) * b'\0' + x_value
y_32 = (32 - len(y_value)) * b'\0' + y_value

compressed = (b'\02' if y_32[31] % 2 == 0 else b'\03') + x_32
uncompressed = b'\04' + x_32 + y_32

print(compressed.hex())    # 02011ae2aa4a47942d486b54e4f3a10cfdba87ffd6bcf0e876ccc605ddf514189c
print(uncompressed.hex())  # 04011ae2aa4a47942d486b54e4f3a10cfdba87ffd6bcf0e876ccc605ddf514189cc1361ddc2122c139359fe9453dda59e753f86741339553572ef24c63e939e694
```

Note that your `compress_point()` does not take padding into account (which is however not relevant for your values, since x and y are 32 bytes), nor does it return the hex encoded value with a leading 0 if the leading byte is single-digit (so `format(x, 'x')` returns the hex encoded value as 63-digit `11ae2aa4a47942d486b54e4f3a10cfdba87ffd6bcf0e876ccc605ddf514189c`).

For completeness: If x and y are already integers, the conversion to padded bytes objects can be implemented simply as follows:

```py
...
x_32 = x.to_bytes(32, 'big')
y_32 = y.to_bytes(32, 'big')
```

---

To convert a compressed key to an uncompressed key, the y value must be reconstructed, which requires modular arrithmetic. For this purpose *ecdsa* can be used (which implements the necessary math under the hood):

```py
from ecdsa import VerifyingKey, SECP256k1
vk = VerifyingKey.from_string(compressed, curve=SECP256k1)
uncompressed = vk.to_string('uncompressed')

print(uncompressed.hex()) # 04011ae2aa4a47942d486b54e4f3a10cfdba87ffd6bcf0e876ccc605ddf514189cc1361ddc2122c139359fe9453dda59e753f86741339553572ef24c63e939e694
```

Likewise, of course, converting an uncompressed key to a compressed one is just as possible.

Note that your `decompress_point()` applies `ecdsa.ellipticcurve.Point()` incorrectly. The constructor requires as 2nd and 3rd parameters x and y coordinates as integers (see 1st code snippet).

---

For completeness: `from_string()` can also handle the raw format, i.e. the concatenation of the 32 bytes x and 32 bytes y coordinate:

```py
...
from ecdsa import VerifyingKey, SECP256k1
raw = x_32 + y_32
vk = VerifyingKey.from_string(raw, curve=SECP256k1)
uncompressed = vk.to_string('uncompressed')

print(uncompressed.hex()) # 04011ae2aa4a47942d486b54e4f3a10cfdba87ffd6bcf0e876ccc605ddf514189cc1361ddc2122c139359fe9453dda59e753f86741339553572ef24c63e939e694
```

Comment: This is a great answer thanks, very well explained, thanks for taking the time